# Why @resource can find all classes implements an interface and inject them as a list

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, interface, inject

I want to inject a list in my application. My code likes this:

```
interface A;
class B implements A;
class C implements A;

class D {
    @Resource
    private list<A> list;
}
```

To inject the `list`, I was going to config the list in an xml，but I found I don't need to. and the list has already been injected into the application when I use `@resource`, I want to know how `@resource` works here.

Comment: It's not `@Resource`, which tells the container to inject instances it already has. You're looking for Spring component scanning.

Comment: I dont see `@resource` annotation being part of Spring boot application. There is a `javax` annotation: `@Resource`. Can you please elaborate your question to include the package name from which `@resource` is being used.

Comment: @Prashant I mean `@Resource`

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as `@Autowired` which is used to inject dependencies.

The differences are that `@Resource` is the standard java annotation (from JSR-250) which Spring also support it for the injection.

I personally use `@Autowired` as  `@Resource` only supports for fields and setter injection while `@Autowired` supports more such as constructors and multi-argument methods injection.

Comment: I'm not asking the different of the two annotation, but I want to know how `@Resource` can make all type A to a list.

Comment: High level reason is that Spring has all metadata about all beans using Reflection .Make all `TypeA` to a list is just equivalent to find out all beans of `TypeA` from the `applicationContext` and then add them to the list one by one .   Is that what you want to know ?

Comment: Sort of. Is there way I can find the source code how `@Resource` work? I didn't find it.

Comment: Check out `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and `DefaultListableBeanFactory#resolveMultipleBeans` , should be helpful in studying how it work.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Resource` annotation tells Spring to look in the application context for any bean matching the desired type and inject it into the variable.

In your case specifying the field as a `List<A>` will indicate to Spring that you want all beans of type A to be injected.

Spring supports the following annotation for DI:

- `@Resource`, of the JavaEE specification for resource name based injections
- `@Inject`, of the JavaEE specification, keeping code compatible
- `@Autowired`, Spring specific counter part of @Inject

Comment: I know `@Resource` can do it. but I want to know how it works, or where I can find how it works.

Comment: Like stated it indicates that Spring needs to look in the application context for matching beans. The application context contains all instances of classes marked with a bean qualifying annotation (eg. Bean Service Component)